# How to get row id in the next example

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I need to show the row id of the clicked anchor element in `showId()`:

```js
function showId() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id'); //This return undefined
            
    alert(id);
    return false;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
     <tr>
            <th>header1</th> 
            <th>header2</th>    
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr id=1>
            <td><a href="" onclick="return showId()">row1 td1</td> 
            <td><a href="" onclick="return showId()">row1 td2</td>    
        </tr>
        <tr id=2>
            <td><a href="" onclick="return showId()">row2 td1</td> 
            <td><a href="" onclick="return showId()">row2 td2</td>    
        </tr>
        <tr id=3>
            <td><a href="" onclick="return showId()">row3 td1</td> 
            <td><a href="" onclick="return showId()">row3 td2</td>    
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: So, you need the clicked on item's parent's parent's id.  Google DOM traversal.  Also, the value of the id should be in quotes (`id="1"`)

Comment: None of your links are closed. Also, avoid inline event handlers

Comment: $(this).parent().attr("id");

Comment: Use closet with tag name, instead of parent.parent it is not the right way as if any label of element get changed code will break.                                                  
function showId(item) { 
var id = $(item).closest('tr').attr('id');            
alert(id);
return false;
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to send clicked element as parameter, so the function have an element to start.

- Start from: item
- First parent node: td = `item.parentNode`
- Second parent node: tr = `item.parentNode.parentNode`

```js
function showId(item) {
    var id = item.parentNode.parentNode.id;
            
    alert(id);
    return false;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>header1</th> 
        <th>header2</th>    
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr id="1">
        <td><a href="" onclick="return showId(this)">row1 td1</td> 
        <td><a href="" onclick="return showId(this)">row1 td2</td>    
    </tr>
    <tr id="2">
        <td><a href="" onclick="return showId(this)">row2 td1</td> 
        <td><a href="" onclick="return showId(this)">row2 td2</td>    
    </tr>
    <tr id="3">
        <td><a href="" onclick="return showId(this)">row3 td1</td> 
        <td><a href="" onclick="return showId(this)">row3 td2</td>    
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: $(item).closest('tr').attr('id'); is better than item.parentNode.parentNode.id; because of item.parentNode.parentNode will break on change of items label.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `$(this)` refers to your anchor tag. However, the id attribute is defined in the `tr` tag.

You need to 'move up' the tree to the parent of the parent element. To do this, try

```
var id = $(this).parent.parent.attr('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

Attention, ID attributes should be in "".
like id="1"

```
function showId(sender) {
var id = $(sender).parent().attr('id'); 

alert(id);
return false;
}



<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>header1</th> 
        <th>header2</th>             
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr id="1"> //Attention ID in "1"
        <td><a href="" onclick="return showId(this)">row1 td1</td> 
        <td><a href="" onclick="return showId(this)">row1 td2</td>           
    </tr>
    <tr id="2">
        <td><a href="" onclick="return showId(this)">row2 td1</td> 
        <td><a href="" onclick="return showId(this)">row2 td2</td>           
    </tr>
    <tr id="3">
        <td><a href="" onclick="return showId(this)">row3 td1</td> 
        <td><a href="" onclick="return showId(this)">row3 td2</td>           
    </tr>
</tbody>
```